# jQuery return the second table cell after the match?

Tags: jquery, find, html-table, match, siblings

This code is working, but I think it's anchoring on the wrong tag.  Here I believe it's saying on the first match of aaaaa, return the cell value for the next div, because it happens to be under a dive.  But now that I also want to pull the value of 3rd td on a match.  How can I change this code so that I can use it get both of the subsequent cells when a match is found.

```
var bodyprefix  = $('#issuetbl td:contains(aaaa)').siblings().find('div').html();
```

For example, given aaaa, I want var1=whatever and var2=cccc

I'm okay with running it twice, but would like the same function based on index or nth-child.

```
<tr>
<td>aaaa</td>
<td><div>whatever</div></td>
<td>cccc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1111</td>
<td><div>something</div></td>
<td>2222</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) instead of `siblings`:

```
var bodyprefixes = [];
$('#issuetbl td:contains(aaaa)').nextAll().find('div').each(function(i, k) {
    bodyprefixes.push($(k).html());
});
```

`bodyprefixes` is now an array of all the values.

Comment: Very close.  I've updated your example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/8RvgA/1/  Now it takes into account that some elements have a child div, and some do not.

Comment: Many thanks. using your code! For some reason it does not pull the full <td> when it encounters <p> or linefeeds like this http://jsfiddle.net/8RvgA/3/ Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more than what you asked for with portions for illustrative purposes, but allows for more flexibility:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var str = 'aaaa';
    var bodyprefixes = [];
    $("tr").each(function(k,v){
        var tds = $(this).children();
        var len = tds.length;
        $.each(tds, function(x,y){
            b = $(y).html(); 
            if(b == str){
                for(var i=0;i<len-1;i++){
                    bodyprefixes.push($(tds[i+1]).html());
                }
            }
        });
    });
    $.each(bodyprefixes, function(u,w){
        $("#variables").append("Var"+u+"= "+w+" <br>");
    });
});
</script>
<table id="issuetbl" border="1">
<tr> 
<td>aaaa</td> <td><div>whatever</div></td> <td>cccc</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>1111</td> <td><div>something</div></td> <td>2222</td> </tr> 
</table>
<div id="variables"></div>
```